# Pynsist packaging packages incorrectly

Tags: python, packaging, pynsist

I'm trying this new tool out to distribute Python projects, which is called Pynsist (http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

It works great and everything but for some reason no packages are found after install, what solves the problem is if you move packages from "pkg" folder to the main folder, which is really peculiar. My installer.cfg:

```
[Application]
name=Seek scrapper
version=1.0
# How to launch the app - this calls the 'main' function from the 'myapp' package:
entry_point=Scrape_pages_to_txt:main

[Python]
version=3.3.5
bitness=32

[Include]
# Importable packages that your application requires, one per line
packages = requests
     bs4
     selenium
     xlsxwriter

# Other files and folders that should be installed
files = ad_urls.txt
    xlsx_writer.py
    Scrape_ads_from_urls.py
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for using pynsist! Can you try adding `Scrape_pages_to_txt` to the `packages` list?